# How to export best post processing feasible solution from CPLEX OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

I solve a multi vehicle routing problem with CPLEX studio IDE 12.10.0 and many of my instances give error because of insufficient RAM. I even put a timelimit to see the best solution, however the process cannot reach the timelimit. Therefore, I cannot review any solution at the end of the process. I had some research and in my .ops file, I enabled "postprocess feasible solutions" which provide me to see the feasible solutions found so far in "Solutions" window. The problem occurs in that part. I can easily see the distance values of vehicles. However, i cannot say it for the other variables.

I have two variables with four and five indexes. At "Solutions" window, these variables reported as vectors. Consequently i cannot sketch the tours. The thing i want to know is whether there are any way to report the best solution found so far in a proper manner. If cplex finds an optimal solution, i can view the variables in a tabular form just like the image below;

[Tabular Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqhKl.png)

Is there a way for turning the solutions in tabular form, and if it is possible, export the solution into an .xmls file.

Answer (score 0):

To save memory instead of running your model in the OPL IDE you may use command line oplrun.

And in the postprocess block you may save your solution into a file through IloOplOutputFile.

Example from https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplscripting/blob/main/zooandsaveresultindatfile.mod

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
} 

execute
{
  var o=new IloOplOutputFile("zooresult.dat");
  o.writeln("nbBus40=",nbBus40,";");
  o.writeln("nbBus30=",nbBus30,";");
  o.close();
}

/*
generates zooresult.dat
nbBus40=6;
nbBus30=2;
*/
```

Then later on your may use that generated file to see the result in the IDE

```
int nbBus40=...;
int nbBus30=...;

execute
{
  
  writeln("nbBus40=",nbBus40);
  writeln("nbBus30=",nbBus30);
  
}

/*

nbBus40=6
nbBus30=2

*/
```

Comment: Hello Alex. I tried to write my decision variable, but it seem i do something wrong. In your example, ıt is only one decision variable. How can i write an array decision variable? Is there any example. Regards...